# Spring cloud stream with resilience4j Circuitbreaker

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, resilience4j

When using circuit breaker, if the consumer goes to open state it throws `CallNotPermittedException` while consuming the event.

But if the consumer has auto commit configured, all the events in the open state will be lost, as CallNotPermittedException is not currently handled in spring cloud and commit is happening after the retries configured.

So, what is the solution on using circuit breaker with spring cloud stream kafka. Is it using manual acknowledgement and fallback method only?